# FakeItEasy Returns different value for subsequent calls to the mock method

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, fakeiteasy

I have a function called GetNumber() in Math class. I would like to return **1** for  the first call, **2** for the second call and so on. I have done this in Mockito something like this

```
when(mathObj.GetNumber()).thenReturn(1).thenReturn(2).thenReturn(3);
```

How can I do the same with FakeItEasy

```
A.CallTo( () => mathObj.GetNumber()).Returns("")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Return Values Calculated at Call Time](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/specifying-return-values/#return-values-calculated-at-call-time) and [Changing behavior between calls](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changing-behavior-between-calls/) for a few examples. One option is

```
A.CallTo(() => mathObj.GetNumber()).ReturnsNextFromSequence(1, 2, 3);
```

another is

```
A.CallTo(() => mathObj.GetNumber())
    .Returns(1).Once()
    .Then
    .Returns(2).Once()
    .Then
    .Returns(3).Once();
```